# ngrok is not yet ready to start tunnels

Tags: ngrok

getting error after run **gulp ngrok-serve**

[23:35:35] 'start-ngrok' errored after 25 s
[23:35:35] NgrokClientError in plugin "yoteams-build.core"
Message:
ngrok is not yet ready to start tunnels
Details:
response: [object Object]
body: [object Object]

[23:35:35] 'start-ngrok' errored after 25 s
[23:35:35] NgrokClientError in plugin "yoteams-build.core"
Message:
ngrok is not yet ready to start tunnels
Details:
response: [object Object]
body: [object Object]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I think this is more suited as an issue in the ngrok-serve repository. I think you'll find more help there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is still facing this same error, first try to create an account on NGROK website and download the current NGROK version. After unzip the NGROK, you should try to add your authtoken to the NGROK.exe file (it's all described in the Setup and Installation menu, they will provide you your token).
And don't forget to check your e-mail box in order to validate your account. Otherwise you wont be able to start tunnels connection with NGROK.

Afterwards I bealieve you will be able to run the command **gulp ngrok-serve**.